# Structure with same name, different definitions: segmentation fault with -O2

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, translation-unit

I've encountered a segmentation fault in a C++ program when two C++ files compiled together each include a different definition of a structure (with the same name).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034277/same-name-structure-with-different-definition-in-c), I understand that structure definitions are restricted to the translation unit (the file and its inclusions).

However, I get a crash when enabling -O1 or more at compile time.
The following minimal code reproduced the segfault.

The code is in 3 short C++ files and 2 headers:

```cpp
// td_collision1.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "td1.h"

struct Data
{
  long a;
  double m1;
  double m2;
};

void sz1(void) {
    std::cout << "Size of in collision1: " << sizeof(struct Data) << std::endl;
}

void collision1(void) {
    struct Data tmp;
    std::vector<struct Data> foo;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        tmp.a = 1;
        tmp.m1 = 0;
        tmp.m2 = 0;
        foo.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
// td1.h
#include <iostream>

void collision1(void);
void sz1(void);

// td_collision2.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "td2.h"

struct Data {
  long a;
  double m1; // note that there is one member less here
};

void sz2(void) {
    std::cout << "Size of in collision2: " << sizeof(struct Data) << std::endl;
}

void collision2(void) {
    struct Data tmp2;
    std::vector<struct Data> bar;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        tmp2.a = 1;
        tmp2.m1 = 0;
        bar.push_back(tmp2); // errors occur here
    }
}
// td2.h
#include <iostream>

void collision2(void);
void sz2(void);

// td_main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "td1.h"
#include "td2.h"

int main(void) {
    sz1();
    sz2();
    collision2();
}
```

This code compiled with GCC 6.3 with -O0 flag runs fine and without error under valgrind.
However, running it with -O1 or O2 leads to the following output:

```
Size of in collision1: 24
Size of in collision2: 16
==326== Invalid write of size 8
==326==    at 0x400F6C: construct<Data, const Data&> (new_allocator.h:120)
==326==    by 0x400F6C: construct<Data, const Data&> (alloc_traits.h:455)
==326==    by 0x400F6C: push_back (stl_vector.h:918)
==326==    by 0x400F6C: collision2() (td_collision2.cc:22)
==326==    by 0x400FE8: main (td_main.cc:10)
==326==  Address 0x5aba1f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 96 alloc'd
==326==    at 0x4C2E1FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: allocate (alloc_traits.h:416)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: _M_allocate (stl_vector.h:170)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: void std::vector<Data, std::allocator<Data> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<Data const&>(Data const&) (vector.tcc:412)
==326==    by 0x400F7E: push_back (stl_vector.h:924)
==326==    by 0x400F7E: collision2() (td_collision2.cc:22)
==326==    by 0x400FE8: main (td_main.cc:10)
==326== 
==326== Invalid write of size 8
==326==    at 0x400F69: construct<Data, const Data&> (new_allocator.h:120)
==326==    by 0x400F69: construct<Data, const Data&> (alloc_traits.h:455)
==326==    by 0x400F69: push_back (stl_vector.h:918)
==326==    by 0x400F69: collision2() (td_collision2.cc:22)
==326==    by 0x400FE8: main (td_main.cc:10)
==326==  Address 0x5aba1f8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 96 alloc'd
==326==    at 0x4C2E1FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: allocate (alloc_traits.h:416)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: _M_allocate (stl_vector.h:170)
==326==    by 0x400DE9: void std::vector<Data, std::allocator<Data> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<Data const&>(Data const&) (vector.tcc:412)
==326==    by 0x400F7E: push_back (stl_vector.h:924)
==326==    by 0x400F7E: collision2() (td_collision2.cc:22)
==326==    by 0x400FE8: main (td_main.cc:10)
==326== 
==326== 
==326== HEAP SUMMARY:
==326==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==326==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 73,896 bytes allocated
==326== 
==326== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==326== 
==326== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==326== ERROR SUMMARY: 191 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

the `push_back()` function fails when the libc reallocates `std::vector<struct Data> bar`. (in my case, its size is 4 items initially, and the vector is further resized afterwards when calling push_back() in the loop.)
When `struct Data` in td_collision1.cc has the same size as in td_collision2.cc, the program doesn't crash.

Therefore, there seem to be a collision between these two structure definitions. Indeed, if I rename one structure, the bug obviously vanishes.
But, as mentioned above, I thought that this could not happen. What did I misunderstood?
Also, if I get rid of function `collision1()`, the segfault vanishes (`struct Data` in collision1 is probably ditched by the compiler because unused)

My understanding was that there exist a clear separation between these two CC files and no "crosstalk" should be possible if the structures are not present in the header.

Edit: add missing td2.h

Comment: It's undefined behavior

Comment: [*One Definition Rule*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). "I understand that structure definitions are restricted to the translation unit (the file and its inclusions)." - Not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but that sounds wrong. If you want something that is local only to a particular `.cpp` file, put it in an [*unnamed namespace*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces).

Comment: Seriously, Why tag C? You don't provide a [mcve], What is it in "td2.h"? I can't reproduce! I loose my time with your question.

Comment: *Off topic: you can use `foo.push_back(Data{1, 0, 0});` or since C++11 `foo.emplace_back(1, 0, 0);` to shorten a code*

Comment: @Stargateur: you're right, it was incorrectly tagged (I wrongly followed the suggestions of the system). Also I missed one (straightforward) include. Right again. That said, nobody forces you to read and answer my questions.

Comment: @user7378105 Sorry, I was too aggressive. I'm not a native english speaker so I only do short sentence. That lead to be less verbose.

Comment: @BoBTFish that's what I was looking for I guess, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer you linked is for C language, and C is not C++.

In C++ (quote from [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), see [Danh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481083/2666289) for the standard), the rule is as follow:

> There can be more than one definition in a program, as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit, of each of the following: class type [...], as long as all of the following is true:
>
> - each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)
> - [...]
>
> If all these requirements are satisfied, the program behaves as if there is only one definition in the entire program. Otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

Your two definitions clearly violates the first condition, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: "In C, you can have multiple definitions of the same type in different translation units" - That's wrong! The _one definition rule_ also applies to C, of course.

Comment: @Olaf The *One Definition Rule* is a C++ concept, not applicable as it is to C. C does not define a *One Definition Rule*, the closest you can find is probably 6.27/3 (C11): *"All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
otherwise, the behavior is undefined."*. Actually, you can have multiple definitions in C++, as long as the definitions follows the rule defined by [basic.def.odr](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6), the C++ rules are simply stricter than the C ones.

Comment: Thank you. I am not a C++ expert as you can see. However I ran into that issue on a project and was very surprised by this behavior because: 1) the compiler doesn't warn me, 2) I expected a clear separation between the code in each file, since nothing is shared via headers. edit: I guess that's why namespaces should be used...

Comment: @Holt: Read the citation you posted in your comment **carefully** again: "All **declarations** that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." - **Declarations**, not *definitions** as you write in your answer! Something like `int i;` at file-scope is a _tentative_ definition only. It becomes a definition if ther is no "true" definition (i.e. with initialiser), in which case all tentative definitions are fold into a single definition (resp. the first tentative definition becomes a full definition, the rest is treated as declaration.

Comment: Strictly speaking there are no "type definitions". `typedef is an alias and _declarations_ is basically what the standard provides, more exactly: type specifiers as part of a _declaration_. But that is about variable declaration and definiton, not about types. You confuse very different concepts - not helpful! You want to search for "tentative definition" in the standard.

Comment: @Olaf I have deleted my last comment and removed the part of the answer about C which was in all cases irrelevant here. Even after going through a huge part of the C standard, this particular case is still unclear for me, so I will dig a bit more before adding anything... If you have any strong references to the standard, I'll be happy to read them.

Comment: @Holt: I'll leave my comment nevertheless, as it might help you to get the pieces together by reading the standard with it in mind. Indeed, as you stated C and C++ are different languages and have diverged even more with C++11 and C99 (C11 mostly adds features, but is otherwise quite close to C99).

Answer (score 1):

From [basic.def.odr](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6), (... is omitted by me):

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause [class]), ..... Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then:
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - ...
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the template's enclosing scope used in the template definition ([temp.nondep]), and also to dependent names at the point of instantiation ([temp.dep]). If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the behavior is as if there were a single definition of D. **If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.**

In your program, definition of `struct Data` in `td_collision1.cc` and in `td_collision2.cc` doesn't match with each other, hence, definitions of `struct Data` do not satisfy those requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're linking a C answer, but your question is about C++. Two languages, two standards, two answers.

That said, I believe the C answer should *also* be that it's disallowed, per the One Definition Rule (which both languages have). Violating that is Undefined Behavior, which includes Segmentation Faults.